# I want to upload javascript to my leadpage page

Tags: javascript

I want to upload javascript to my leadpage page so that i can play with html tag in my leadpages.

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    var current = new Date();
    var expiry  = new Date("June 2, 2018 22:16:00")
    var expiry2 = new Date("June 2, 2018 22:20:30")

    if(current.getTime()>expiry2.getTime()){
        console.log('Enter First If');
        $('#before').hide();
        $('#onDate').hide();

        var $frame = $('iframe#summitVideo');
        $frame.attr('src','');

        $('#after').show();       
    }else if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
        console.log('Enter Second If');        
        $('#before').hide();
        $('#onDate').show();  
     }else{
        $('#before').show(); 
     }

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: I want to know how can i upload this script to leadpages.

Comment: You are basically asking how to include script in a page which is very easy to research. Basic research is expected before asking questions here

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp 
just upload and implement it

Answer (score 1):

You can have it on a .js file and link it in your HTML using the `<script>` tag or by placing an `<script>` tag inline in the document (before closing the `<body>` tag).
Make sure to add it after your jQuery script and a proper event handler.